# Is Python 2 Standard environment in Google App Engine going to be deprecated/closed soon?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have a number of projects deployed to Python 2 Standard environment in Google App Engine and started to worry what will happen after January 1, 2020 when Python 2 will become not maintained.

Does Google provide some hints if it's going to keep Python 2 Standard environment in App Engine for a long time? Or should I start migrating? In some projects migration is going to be painful due to ndb and other google libraries, which are not supported anywhere else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently came across [this post from Google on the GAE Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/dTXJgeFw4yQ) that addresses this:

> You needn't fear for the Python 2.7 apps already deployed. 2020 is not as critical a date as may appear at first sight. Python 2.7 will get support for the benefit of existing Google App Engine (GAE) customers using Python 2.7 well beyond this date.
>
> Everyone is equally aware of difficulties faced by those who migrate a Python 2.7 GAE application to the 3.x series. Quite a few tools and infrastructure adjustments will facilitate this task, so developers should not feel too concerned. A smooth transition is in everyone's interest.

So it seems we don't need to rush (thank goodness!).